# Add custom rewrite rule so wordpress won't overide it

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

This is my htaccess file, wordpress multisite htacces. I need to put my custom rule in there and not let wordpress aoverride it. How can i do that? The bold one is my custom rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

**MY CUSTOM RULE RewriteRule ^/\?currentpage=(\d+)$ currentpage/$1.html [NC,L]**

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `RewriteRule` you can only check the URI path and not the query. You need to use `RewriteCond` and *QUERY_STRING* for the URI query:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^currentpage=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^$ currentpage/%1.html [NC,L]
```